# Exit for loop by user (cancel button)

Tags: c#, button, abort, cancel-button

i am facing a trouble in my program. the program is a login checker, it reads a list of user & passwords then it test the login 1 by 1.
the problem i am facing is when i put a long list the program take a while and so it needs a cancel button or pause. while the program running in that loop (login tests) the window form freezes and i cant press any buttons or even drug it around.
here is the loop:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string spl = textBox5.Text;
    int lin = textBox4.Lines.Count();

    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++)
    {
        string dick = textBox4.Lines[i];
        Convert.ToString(dick);
        string[] wordArray = dick.Split(':');

        textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToString(wordArray[0]));
        textBox2.Text = (Convert.ToString(wordArray[1]));
        login();
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of application it is?

Comment: Can you please explain what is textBox1..2..3..4..5..6..7.??? where is your list of user ids? why aren't you using querying such as linq? `dick`??

Comment: "drug it around" quote of the day. Look into Threading, Tasks, Background workers and CancellationTokens. There so many way to handle this the response will be quite lengthy. Basically your form is "freezing" because all the work (looping) is done on the UI Thread. If possible this should be on another thread, thus keeping the UI responsive. Cancellation the operation is up to you to handle but there are many easy to implement methods OOB. Good luck.

Comment: @joseph its login check, u open users list with passwords and it checks which users is able to login.

Comment: @andrew  list of users&pass at textbox4, 1st it needs to split email from password, so textbox1 received email and textbox2 received passwords. textbox4 is unused (it was for something else) idk about linq and dick is the variable of splitting method i used

Comment: Why are you converting things (`dick`, `wordarray[i]`) to strings that are already strings? Strings are strings, are strings... converting them to strings won't change anything. `textBox4.Lines` is an array. You can check the length of it with `textBox4.Lines.Length`. This is more efficient than `Count()` (a LINQ extension method)` that enumerates the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly I would like to tell you why you are faced with such a problem.**
    You are doing a 'heavy' operation in the main thread(UI thread), and while this thread is busy working with the task(checking for users and passwords), it will not response to the UI messages. That is, it will not check weather the message queue is empty or not, so it will do nothing with your clicking until the operation is over.
**Secondly, I would like to find several ways to solve it.**
**Solution 1** Use a background thread to do the work

```
    using System.Threading;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                string spl = textBox5.Text;
                int lin = textBox4.Lines.Count();
                for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
                    string dick = textBox4.Lines[i];
                    Convert.ToString(dick);
                    string[] wordArray = dick.Split(':');

                    textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToString(wordArray[0]));
                    textBox2.Text = (Convert.ToString(wordArray[1]));
                    login();
                }
            }));
        });
        thread.Start();
    }
```

By this way, your UI with response to you when you are doing the operation.

**Solution 2** Use a BackgroundWorker
    It is similar to solution 1, just replace the user-created background thread with *System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker*, as for how to user a BackgroundWorker, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx for more information.

**Solution 3** Use ThreadPool
    Use System.Threading.ThreadPool to create the background thread to work for you. In this way, you won't have to manage the thread by yourself. For more information, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=VS.80).aspx

**Solution 4** Use a Task
    Use System.Threading.Task to do your operation. see msdn:
    https:// msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx
    Attention: *System.Threading.Task* is availble from .NET Framework 4.0.

**BTW**, if you use the solution above, remember to use **Form.Invoke()** to access your control on the form, or set **Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls** to false.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because it's running on the UI thread. If you're using .net >=4.5, try using the [Task.Run()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx)

In addition you can use a cancellation token to stop the login-process

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is simply a threading problem. You Login method is running on the default thread, which is the thread the UI uses. So while your code is using this thread to try to login, the execution of actions on the UI is blocked because the thread is busy.

What you need to do is to let your Login run on another thread so it doesn't block the UI thread. This can be done using different methods, for example [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx). Both of these also support cancellation, which means that it is possible to trigger them to stop doing their current operation.

Comment: i understand the problem, but can u post an example ? i google it but still having issues implementing it in my code

Comment: Just click the links in my answer, these are tutorials on how to use Tasks and Backgroundworkers from the MSDN. You need to apply this to your own code of course, but this is something you should know as a developer, since multi-threading is an often used technique that you probably will need to use in other projects.

Comment: No problem, we all had to learn this at some point :) You normally don't even need to exactly know how to apply it, if you just know that it exists and then you can look it up. Also, please mark this (or Dimitris post, since it's similar) as answer if this helped to solve your problem.